# Command-line to compile Win32 "hello world" in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2005

The following basic Win32 program compiles just fine in Dev-C++.

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    MessageBox(NULL,"Hello, world!","My app", MB_OK ) ;
}
```

But now I'm trying to compile it using Visual Studio 2005. I open the Visual Studio command prompt and type:

```
cl test.cpp
```

But I get the following errors:

```
test.cpp
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function _WinMain@16
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I thought the problem might be the path for the linker, but according to this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the linker looks for it in the enviromental variable `LIB` which is already set in the Visual Studio prompt to:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\LIB;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\lib;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\lib;
```

What else is needed to compile a Win32 program in the command line?

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 SP1 update for Vista.

Comment: Are Visual Studio 2008 libraries compatible with Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: What has VS2008 to do in all this?

Comment: Your path points to VS 2008

Comment: I believe VS2005 is version 8 and VS2008 is version 9

Comment: Why are you using an 8-year-old compiler when there are much newer (and free) options available like Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, Because I read somewhere that with VS2005 you are able to target your builds to older frameworks and Windows versions

Comment: @GetFree: You can still target older versions of Windows with newer compilers, you just need to make sure that you ship the proper runtime redistributable with your program and that you don't use newer API functions that didn't exist on older OS versions (or use proper runtime checks with `GetProcAddress()` etc.).  And if you have the source code or the proper libs+headers to older frameworks, you can certainly use those as well with newer compilers, but make sure everything links against the same version of the C runtime library.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I also read that Google Chrome is compiled with with VS2005. I don't why, but it might be for a good reason. Basically I'm trying to avoid too-new technologies, so whatever I do will work in the wider range of environments.

Comment: @Adam If Microsoft decides to ship quality products again, your advice to use their latest toolset may become valid. With Visual Studio 2012, both the RTC and every Update featured **compiler bugs**, not just for esoteric language constructs. VS 2010 was the last quality release. For a commercial project I probably wouldn't suggest anything younger than that.

Comment: @GetFree: I don't know where you read that, but the [official Chrome build instructions](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows) say to use VS 2010.

Comment: @IInspectable: Fascinating, I was not aware of the compiler bugs in VS 2012+.  That's a good reason to avoid using VS 2012/2013, but 2008 and 2010 are still vastly superior products to 2005.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I remember to have read that during the first years of Chrome's existense. May be now they use something newer, but at that time VS2008 existed already and they didn't use it. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=VS.90).aspx) you can see that VS2008 no longer supports older OSs. Also, as a personal policy, I don't use newer technologies unless I need them, and since I just care about the compiler and not the visual environment, I'm OK with VS2005 for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `user32.lib` to the command: it's an import library for `user32.dll`, which is linked in by default by g++, but not by Visual C++.

In general, just check the documentation of whatever function the linker protests about.

---

Note that you do not need to use that non-standard Microsoft monstrosity `WinMain`.

Instead just use standard C++ `main`.

Then with Microsoft's linker, if you want a GUI subsystem executable add option `/entry:mainCRTStartup`.

---

Minimal C++03 example:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox( 0, L"Hello, world!", L"My app:", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
}
```

Building from command line with Visual C++ 12.0 as GUI subsystem executable:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> set cl & set link
CL=/EHsc /GR /FI"iso646.h" /Zc:strictStrings /we4627 /we4927 /wd4351 /W4 /D"_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /nologo
LINK=/entry:mainCRTStartup /nologo

[D:\dev\test]
> cl winhello.cpp /Fe"hello" /link /subsystem:windows user32.lib
winhello.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the User32 library. Add this just below your includes

```
#pragma comment(lib,"User32.lib")
```

#pragma lets you provide additional information to the compiler

#pragma comment (lib, "library.lib") allows the user to pass this comment to the linker to specify additional libraries to link

Comment: Might consider including some info on what that `#pragma` does and why the OP should use it.

Comment: My opinion is that since this is not a source-code related issue, the solution should not be source-code related either.

Answer (score -3):

COMMAND LINE COMPILATION OF A WIN32 APPLICATIO USING C

cl w1.c /subsystem:windows gdi32.dll user32.dll

SET THE FOLLOWING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
INCLUDE
LIB
PATH

Comment: This is pretty crap. You must link lib files, not dll.